# How can i deobfuscate this text?

Tags: text, lua, deobfuscation

I've recently found some lua code and what I found inside was some obfuscated string. That made me wonder what sort of obfuscation technique was used there. Does anybody have an idea?

`240.06230.0575240.06240.06270.0675250.0625265.06625270.0675250.0625285.07125260.065260.065260.065250.0625265`...
https://pastebin.com/raw/7RkxjWQw

Comment: You should provide the script of decoder (the whole script where this string was found).

Comment: SO is not a place for guessing what certain string is encoded with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this string is splitted into `xxx.yyyy...` chunks (exactly three digits before decimal point), then multiply each number by `800/4001` (the results will be integer!), then convert these integer numbers to ASCII, the hidden sequence of 16 floating point numbers would be revealed:

```
0.0062562944425795
0.036286507766961
0.02127140110477
0.047547837763604
0.041291543321025
0.0025025177770318
0.011261329996643
0.018768883327738
0.017517624439223
0.042542802209541
0.037537766655477
0.016266365550707
0.0087588122196113
0.057557908871731
0.025025177770318
0.026276436658834
```

Is the puzzle stops here?
Or should we try to decipher it further?

---

Ok, we could multiply them all by `32767/41` (the results will be integer!)

```
5
29
17
38
33
2
9
15
14
34
30
13
7
46
20
21
```

Hmm, the puzzle seems to be really interesting...
Is it the end?

---

Just googled it.
That's the passwords encrypted, something Roblox-related
So, OP surely doesn't have decoder script :-)

---

Ok, finally did it.

```
function decode_password(encoded_password)
   local result = ""
   local buffer = ""
   for x in encoded_password:gsub("%d%d%d%.", "\0%0"):gmatch"%Z+" do
      x = math.floor(tonumber(x) / 5.00125 + 0.5)
      if x ~= 95 then
         buffer = buffer..string.char(x)
      elseif buffer ~= "" then
         x = math.floor(tonumber(buffer) * 799.195122 + 0.5)
         result = result..("qazwsxedcrfjmik,o0 23456-=\\vtgbyhnul.p;;;/[']1789"):sub(x, x)
         buffer = ""
      end
   end
   return result
end
```

Example 1:

```
local p = '240.06230.0575240.06240.06270.0675250.0625265.06625270.0675250.0625285.07125260.065260.065260.065250.0625265.06625275.06875285.07125265.06625475.11875240.06230.0575240.06255.06375270.0675250.0625280.07270.0675265.06625240.06275.06875275.06875270.0675270.0675285.07125270.0675245.06125475.11875240.06230.0575240.06250.0625245.06125250.0625275.06875245.06125260.065240.06245.06125245.06125240.06260.065275.06875275.06875475.11875240.06230.0575240.06260.065275.06875265.06625260.065275.06875280.07255.06375275.06875275.06875270.0675255.06375270.0675240.06260.065475.11875240.06230.0575240.06260.065245.06125250.0625285.07125245.06125265.06625260.065255.06375255.06375250.0625245.06125240.06250.0625265.06625475.11875240.06230.0575240.06240.06250.0625265.06625240.06250.0625265.06625245.06125275.06875275.06875275.06875275.06875240.06255.06375245.06125280.07475.11875240.06230.0575240.06245.06125245.06125250.0625270.0675245.06125255.06375250.0625285.07125285.07125285.07125270.0675270.0675260.065255.06375475.11875240.06230.0575240.06245.06125280.07275.06875270.0675280.07280.07280.07255.06375255.06375250.0625275.06875275.06875255.06375280.07475.11875240.06230.0575240.06245.06125275.06875265.06625245.06125275.06875270.0675250.0625260.065260.065255.06375285.07125250.0625250.0625255.06375475.11875240.06230.0575240.06260.065250.0625265.06625260.065250.0625280.07240.06250.0625250.0625240.06285.07125265.06625260.065245.06125475.11875240.06230.0575240.06255.06375275.06875265.06625255.06375275.06875275.06875270.0675270.0675270.0675265.06625265.06625260.065275.06875275.06875475.11875240.06230.0575240.06245.06125270.0675250.0625270.0675270.0675255.06375270.0675265.06625265.06625265.06625240.06275.06875240.06275.06875475.11875240.06230.0575240.06240.06280.07275.06875265.06625280.07280.07245.06125250.0625250.0625245.06125285.07125270.0675245.06125245.06125255.06375475.11875240.06230.0575240.06265.06625275.06875265.06625265.06625275.06875285.07125240.06280.07280.07275.06875245.06125275.06875255.06375245.06125475.11875240.06230.0575240.06250.0625265.06625240.06250.0625265.06625245.06125275.06875275.06875275.06875275.06875240.06255.06375245.06125280.07475.11875240.06230.0575240.06250.0625270.0675250.0625275.06875270.0675260.065255.06375270.0675270.0675265.06625280.07280.07255.06375260.065475.11875'
print(decode_password(p))  --> stophackingme123
```

Example 2:

```
for _, info in ipairs(loginDatabase) do
   print(info.username, decode_password(info.password))
end
```

Comment: could you decipher a bit more..?

Comment: @NekO_unnamed - Answer updated.  You're a cheater, nevertheless you've brought an interesting problem to solve.